# Difference between Spring's ConsumerSeekAware.onPartitionsAssigned and ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener.onPartitionsAssigned

Tags: spring, apache-kafka

Spring has two interfaces: `ConsumerSeekAware` and `ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener` that provide a similarly named method: `onPartitionsAssigned()`.

I assume the `org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener.onPartitionsAssigned()` behaves like the Kafka  `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRebalanceListener.onPartitionsAssigned()`, getting called every time a partition re-assignment occurs, including at consumer start up.

How does the `org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConsumerSeekAware.onPartitionsAssigned()`  work ?
When does it get called ? On every partition re-assignment or only when the consumer starts listening ?

If I need to force a consumer to start reading from the beginning is it OK to seek to offset 0 on all assigned partitions in the `ConsumerSeekAware.onPartitionsAssigned()` or will that force it to the beginning after every partition re-assignment (e.g during re-balancing) ?